# How to apply grid item header handle to angular2-grid?

Tags: angular

I am using sample code from https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid.

However, as shown in demo (https://bmorton.co.uk/angular/) you can drag grid items only by using blue column header handle and not entire grid item.

How do I achieve such functionality?

Cheers
Sanket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
<div [ngGrid]="gridConfig">
    <div [ngGridItem]="{'dragHandle': '.handle', 'fixed': true, 'col': 2, 'row': 1}">
        <div class="handle">{{text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice `dragHandle` property

See also the corresponding plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/gKEBR7iaurN8aI04g9bU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Can I drag grid item of first into second?
I am trying to achieve Visual Studio toolbox like functionality
From one place where I can see small icons; dragging onto work-space area give me detail feature. Any inputs on this front would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these properties for understanding the module:

```
{
'col': 1,               //  The start column for the item
'row': 1,               //  The start row for the item
'sizex': 1,             //  The start width in terms of columns for the item
'sizey': 1,             //  The start height in terms of rows for the item
'dragHandle': null,     //  The selector to be used for the drag handle. If null, uses the whole item
'resizeHandle': null,   //  The selector to be used for the resize handle. If null, uses 'borderSize' pixels from the right for horizontal resize, 
                        //    'borderSize' pixels from the bottom for vertical, and the square in the corner bottom-right for both
'borderSize': 15,
'fixed': false,         //  If the grid item should be cascaded or not. If yes, manual movement is required
'draggable': true,      //  If the grid item can be dragged. If this or the global setting is set to false, the item cannot be dragged.
'resizable': true       //  If the grid item can be resized. If this or the global setting is set to false, the item cannot be resized.
}
```

For your question,notice that keeping `'dragHandle': null` provides you what you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Can I drag grid item of first into second?
I am trying to achieve Visual Studio toolbox like functionality
From one place where I can see small icons; dragging onto work-space area give me detail feature. Any inputs on this front would be much helpful.